# Wait for time Unity C# when called to

Tags: unity, c#

I am currently programming a custom programming language and using Unity to run it. My current issue is that while loops freeze the game when their done. Is there a simple way to wait until end of frame in unity or wait for time?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Try implementing your solution based on the documentation there, and if you have trouble applying it to your case, **edit your question** to show us more details of where you need help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `while loop` in Unity, you need to use a `Coroutine`.
To demonstrate how to do this, I will show you what you would normally do, and then show how a `coroutine` is different.

## Traditional While Loop Structure

```
void Loop()
{
    while(running)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

## Unity Coroutine Structure

```
IEnumerator Loop()
{
    while(condition)
    {
        // Do stuff here
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

## Example

The following code fades text continuously.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;


public class Transitions : MonoBehaviour
{
    Coroutine fade = null;
    public Text text;
    public float speed = 1;
    void Update()
    {
        if(fade == null)
            fade = StartCoroutine(Fade());
    }

    public IEnumerator Fade()
    {
        Color c = text.color;
        Color target = Color.clear;
        float a = text.color.a;
        while(a > 0)
        {
            a -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
            text.color = new Color(c.r, c.g, c.b, a);
            yield return null;
        }
        text.color = Color.clear;
        while(a < 1)
        {
            a += speed * Time.deltaTime;
            text.color = new Color(c.r, c.g, c.b, a);
            yield return null;
        }
        text.color = c;
        fade = null;
    }
}
```

## Explanation

*(What this does line by line)*

1. When we call `StartCoroutine(Fade());`, we assign it to the `fade` Coroutine variable. This variable holds a pointer to the coroutine.
2. When `fade` completes, we assign it to null to ensure it can be used again.
3. Now that fade is null, the update loop will execute a new iteration of the the `Fade()` Coroutine.

Credit goes to @DMGregory for correcting my use of bool locks and providing the explanation above.

## Valuable Tips

We can break out of the `Coroutine` using `yield break`;

If you do not `yield return null` inside the loop, the `coroutine` does not return between frames and will wait for the loop to end as in a normal `while loop`.

We can break out of the while loop in the `Coroutine`, by using break as per normal.

## Links

For more information regarding the proper implementation and use of coroutines:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer any way you see fit if it will benefit future users. Cheers.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of use here. It might be worth mentioning in your answer why checking before starting the coroutine is advantageous (for avoiding GC allocation), just in case it strikes a reader as unnecessarily complex compared to the bool method you'd shown previously.